# How to implement colorbar next to pcolor map in tkinter (python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, colorbar

I am making an interactive tool with tkinter, and want to map a masked data set against the longitude and latitude (masking based on selection in list boxes) with the help of pcolor. I want a colorbar next to the map. The idea is that if you click the 'select' button that the map will be shown and that if you click the button again that the map is updated.

I tried to use matshow instead of pcolor in order to see if the plotting worked or not. It worked, however I did not work when I used crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(). For the update part I tried to make a new canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Listbox, MULTIPLE, END, Button
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ClassName: 
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width = 1000, height = 350) # create the canvas (tkinter module)
        canvas.pack()

        list = tk.Listbox(master,height=10,width=22)
        list.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        for i in [2,3,4,5]:
            list.insert(tk.END,i)
        canvas.create_window(105,105,window=list)

        select_button = tk.Button(master,text='Select variables',command=lambda: self.selection(list,master))
        canvas.create_window(100,205,window= select_button)

    def selection(self,list,master):
        values= [list.get(idx) for idx in list.curselection()]
        shape = np.random.randint(1, values[0], [5,5])

        lon = np.arange(5)
        lat = np.arange(5)

        fig = Figure(figsize=(4,4))
        a = fig.add_subplot(111)
        tiler = cimgt.StamenTerrain(desired_tile_form='')
        ax = plt.axes(projection=tiler.crs)
        ax.set_extent((0,4,0,4),crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        ax.add_image(tiler,10, cmap='gray')
        c = ax.pcolor(lon,lat,shape,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        fig.colorbar(c)

        canvas1 = tk.Canvas(master,width = 500, height = 400)
        canvas1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        canvas1.draw_idle()
        canvas1.create_window(100,500,window=c)

   root = Tk()
    my_gui = ClassName(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I expect the pcolor map to be shown with the colorbar next to it and this map to update. The colorbar can stay however, I don't mind to update that.

My actual results are that I get a bunch of errors and nothing is plotted.

Comment: Please limit your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As such, your code gives a bunch of errors and it gets harder to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your comment! I adapted my code to a much simpler version (see above).

Comment: I'm getting an error still for `canvas1`. Error: `AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'create_window'`. For this line: `canvas1.create_window(100,500,window=c)`

Comment: Yes I know, I did not solve it yet. If I remove the comment: canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig), canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT) and canvas1.draw_idle(), I don't get the error. However it will plot the graph at the consol instead of the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it differently and now the plotting of the colorbar works. This is what I did.

```
    fig = Figure(figsize=(4,4))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    c = ax.pcolor(lon,lat,shape)
    fig.colorbar(c,ax=ax,fraction=0.046,pad=0.04)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master)

    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=self.clicks)
```